# mayavi python surface plot wrong aspect ratio

Tags: python, mayavi, mayavi.mlab

I'm trying to learn mayavi to plot some 3D data. My xy grid typically looks like this

```
import numpy 
from mayavi import mlab
x,y = numpy.mgrid[0:90:3j, 0:360:3j]
z= #some calculation
mlab.surf(x, y, z)
mlab.show()
```

the plot looks like

[image]

while the plot using gnuplot looks like this

[image]

So, the mayavi image doesn't have proper aspect ratio. How to plot the data properly with mayavi?

Comment: A [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help to figure out the difference between the two plotters.

Answer (score 3):

You can handle that problem by using the `extent` parameter like this

```
import numpy 
from mayavi import mlab
x,y = numpy.mgrid[0:90:3j, 0:360:3j]
z= #some calculation
mlab.surf(x, y, z, extent=(0,1,0,1,0,1))
mlab.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

The horizontal plane generated by gnuplot produces an axis spanning the range 0-90 which looks at least the same length as the perpendicular axis which spans the range 0-400. Considering this fact, I would tend to say that gnuplot is actually the one for which the aspect ratio is wrong, considering your purpose would be to have somehting similar to the matplotlib call `ax.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')`. Additionally, `surf` has the `warp_scale` keyword which allows a vertical exaggeration to be produced. Documentation [here](https://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/mlab_helper_functions.html#mayavi.mlab.surf).